# Is posible to add text to fullcalendar bacground-events?

Tags: fullcalendar

How to display `text1`, `text2`, etc. in background-event?

```
<pre>
{ 
  start: '2019-04-24', 
  end: '2019-04-28', 
  overlap: false, 
  rendering: 'background', 
  color: '#ff9f89' 
  text: 'text1' },
{ 
   start: '2019-04-06', 
   end: '2019-04-08', 
   overlap: false, 
   rendering: 'background', 
   color: '#ff9f89'  
   text: 'text2' 
}
</pre>
```

[image: Expected result.]

Comment: Have you tried manipulating them via the eventRender callback? That would be the obvious place to do it

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well your issue:
You should use the description fields of an event, you can acces it after in a fullcalendar callback like in eventRender for instance:

```
 {id : 12, title : "titleEvent", start: 2019-05-05, description : "description for hover"}

         eventRender: function(info) {
          var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
              });
          },
```

eventRender is called when the event are placed in the calendar so each event will trigger this function: the tooltip comes from tooltip.js and popper.js and they will show the description of your event when hovering on it